# How to foward a specific sender's emails to another Gmail account's inbox?

Tags: gmail

I have several Gmail accounts and I keep missing important  emails from an old Gmail account as I only have time to check my new email address more frequently.

How do I go about fowarding emails from my older Gmail account with a specific word in them to my newer Gmail account?

Is that possible? I have the Gmail app + a S6 & S8 phone.

Note: I cannot update my email address on those important emails to my new Gmail account.

Comment: If I read this correctly, you should be able to invoke some incoming mail rule to forward to the second account. This is almost certainly Gmail-based, and not an Android respective solution.

Comment: @wbogacz But I thought maybe there were some innovative solutions available on just Android using other "tools".

Answer (score 1):

From Gmail [help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en):

**Automatically forward Gmail messages to another account**

You can choose to forward all of your new messages to another email address, or only forward certain types of messages.

**Set up automatic forwarding**

You can automatically forward your messages to another address. You can choose to forward all new messages, or just certain ones.

Note: You can only set up forwarding on your computer, and not on the Gmail app.

The following are the few first steps, further explained at Gmail [help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en):

1. On your computer, open Gmail using the account you want to forward messages from. You can only forward messages for a single Gmail address, and not an email group or alias.
2. In the top right, click Settings (cog).
3. Click **Settings**.
4. Click the **Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab**.
5. Set a repective **Filter** as needed to limit the scope of forwards.
6. In the "Forwarding" section, click **Add a forwarding address**.
7. Enter the email address you want to forward messages to.
8. Click Next and then **Proceed** and then **OK**.

Comment: You should be able to do all of the above, using desktop view in the chrome app